# Checkbox in ModelForms

Tags: python, django

I have model Persons and Model Event, and i want to create a form, where i have list of persons with checkboxes for one event.
What i do wrong?

models.py:

```
class Applications(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Persons, related_name='ApplPer')
    events = models.ForeignKey(Events, related_name='ApplEve')
    add_date = models.DateTimeField('Date', auto_now_add=True)
```

views.py:

```
def events_list(request, slug, event_slug):
        event = models.Events.objects.get(slug=event_slug)
        team_id = models.Druzyny.objects.filter(slug=slug)
        person_list = models.Osoby.objects.filter(dru=team_id).filter(aktywny=1).order_by('nazwisko')

        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = ApplicationForm(request.POST, team=1)
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return render_to_response('strona/events_list.html',
                                          {'slug': slug, 'event_slug': event_slug,
                                           'event': event,'person_list': person_list,
                                           'form': form },
                                          context_instance=RequestContext(request), )
        else:
            form = ApplicationForm(team=1)
        return render_to_response('strona/events_list.html',
                                  {'slug': slug, 'event_slug': event_slug,
                                   'event': event,'person_list': person_list,
                                   'form': form },
                                  context_instance=RequestContext(request), )

class ApplicationForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = models.Applications
        fields = ('imp','oso')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        my_team  = kwargs.pop('team')

        super(ApplicationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['oso'].widget = CheckboxSelectMultiple()
        self.fields['oso'].queryset = models.Osoby.objects.filter(dru=my_team).filter(aktywny=1).order_by('nazwisko')
```

I change view, now i have:

```
int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'
```

I want this result:

```
Person1 [Checkbox]
Person2 [Checkbox]
Person3 [Checkbox]
```

Comment: What is the current result?

Comment: I can show form, but i can't POST data to database.

Comment: What is `fromdata`?  Nothing right? Maybe `form.save()`.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method

Comment: @allcaps, i change it and i have: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'

Comment: @allcaps, can you show me how to create this form, some example?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68594/discussion-between-allcaps-and-piszu).

Comment: Full stack trace please.

Answer (score 0):

You call `fromdata.save()`. But `formdata` isn't your forms data. It's nothing.

To save form data in a modelform you call save on the form itself:

```
form.save()
```

See documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method.

### Update

I don't see the import for models, but is is better to import the needed model only and not the complete module.

```
 import models
```

should be:

```
from .models import Applications
```

Also not that it's better to have singular model names: 'Application'.

Comment: I don't need to see your imports. But the last line in `ApplicationForm` suggests that you wrote `import models`, which could lead to weird errors. It's better to only import the parts that you need: `from .models import Applications`. I requested the stacktrace of the error. What does it say above "'int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'list'".